# Why does the "body[attribute="value] element" CSS selector doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, sass, shadow-dom

Why don't these CSS selector work ? The browser doesn't even detect these rules so nothing is applied.

```css
body[color-theme="light"] ion-input {
  --background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

body[color-theme="dark"] ion-input {
  --background: #1e1e1e;
}
```

My HTML looks like this :

[image]

If I only use the `ion-input` CSS selector though it works, so it seems that the `body[color-theme="dark"]` cause a problem.

Comment: Because you're in the shadow DOM

Comment: You want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context() though it might not stay very long in the specs: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1914

Comment: Read the documentation of the ``<ion-content>`` component you use: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content and https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics